# php command not found while installing composer

Tags: command-line, composer-php, lumen

I am using ubuntu OS. I am trying to install composer.

my $PATH is

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/opt/lampp/bin/php

while entering following command it shows error php is not command

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php --
--install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

error sudo:

php: command not found

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16133)

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: To expand on @thebluefox's comment, what do you see when you run `php -v`? If you get an error, then you haven't installed PHP properly.

Comment: To expand even further, it's likely that your path to the PHP binary is incorrect. `/opt/lampp/bin/php` is probably not a folder but the binary itself, which is incorrect. Try changing that to `/opt/lampp/bin` and running `source` on the bash script defining your $PATH variable. [Check this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/447247/run-php-from-the-command-line) for more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you use PHP7? Then the command should be this.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php70
```